# Why does Java complain that it can't find my local class?

Tags: java, local-class

I am trying to setup Dozer to perform a complex mapping between my two entities.  Essentially, I want it to convert my `percentCompleted` double to a boolean, based on if the value is 1 (100%) or not.

To do this I created the following method:

```
private void initEntityMappings()
{
    BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            class isCompletedConverter implements CustomConverter {
                @Override
                public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class destClass, Class sourceClass) {
                    if (source == null) { return null; }

                    // Make sure the source is a double and the destination is a boolean
                    if (!(source instanceof Double) || !(destination instanceof Boolean))
                        throw new MappingException("Source was not a double or destination was not a boolean");

                    Boolean castedDest = (Boolean)destination;
                    Double castedSrc = (Double)source;
                    castedDest = castedSrc == 1;

                    return castedDest;
                }
            };

            mapping(TaskDetailsViewModel.class, TaskSummaryViewModel.class)
                .fields("percentCompleted", "isCompleted", customConverter(isCompletedConverter));
        }
    };  
}
```

The problem is that it the `.fields()` call complains because it says it can't find the symbol for `isCompletedConverter`.  As this is my first time doing a local class, I am sure I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out exactly what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the *token* `isCompletedConverter` (as oppose to an instance of `isCompletedConverter`, or it's `.class` object) which isn't valid at the particular point you use it. The way you're including it is kind of like in a cast, or an `instanceof` check, but that's a different syntax from a method invocation as `customConverter` appears to be.

Either try `isCompletedConverter.class`, or `new isCompletedConverter()` depending on what `customConverter()` is doing (I can't tell from the given code). It also might become clearer if you rename the local class from `isCompletedConverter` to `IsCompletedConverter` to match regular Java conventions.

Comment: Ahh, `isCompletedConverter.class` worked, and now I see why.  Also good call on the java conventions.